# Error in Hmisc Package installation and require command (MAC M1)

Tags: r, macos, statistics, hmisc

I just tried to install "Hmisc" package via R software on my MAC (M1) and received the following error:

```
> require(Hmisc)
```

```
Loading required package: Hmisc
**Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Hmisc’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘interp**’
```

Tried to Re-install but uncessfully.

Comment: The error tells you that you need to install the "interp" package before installing Hmisc. Try `install.packages("interp")` then try installing Hmisc again.

Comment: Perfect! worked. Thank you!